# Question on isomorphisms : is this true $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\le\mathbb{T}$?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

I've shown $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \le\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} $ and I've shown $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \cong\mathbb{T}$ where $\mathbb{T}$ is the circle group.

So I was wondering if $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\le\mathbb{T}$ follows from this?

Thanks!

Comment: It follows that $\mathbb{T}$ contains an isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You actually commit an abuse of languagre (but totally admissoble) of naming  an isomorphic image of the endomorphism image of a group iafter this group.